# How to "auto-click" on a WebView in Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, automation

I already searched the forum and the internet but I could not find a solution to this, please help me!

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 and API Level 18 / USB device.

I need to automatically "click" on buttons and lists in an app I'm developing, entirely based on WebView.

Example with http://m.facebook.com

1. Click the button "Create new account"
2. Enter name, surname, email, male gender and choose date of birth 10/01/1990

Comment: I need this automatic click to be part of the app, not something separate, so that even after generating the apk and publishing in the Play Store the app works that way.

Comment: I have added an answer check if it will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

For rich features like you mentioned, instead of using webview try making a web app([link](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/))

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is it possible to generate apk and publish in the Play Store?

Comment: Yeah, Web app is just a new approach for low resource consumption. Check this blog to generate apk out of it.  (https://zolmeister.com/2014/01/how-to-turn-webapp-into-native-android.html)

Comment: Got it. Do you recommend moving to Cordova?

Comment: webapps are better approach when app is mostly dependent on webview.

Comment: Got it. Can you describe some of PWA's advantages over the hybrid apps for this case?

Taking advantage ... If I'm going to develop a PWA, can I also reuse this app for iOS?

Comment: It's just a different approach when App is majorly dependent over Webview (webPages). Hybrid apps and Native apps have different purpose, you can easily find blogs about the differences. I am not sure about IOS but there must be some wrapper to convert PWA to IOS app

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some features may fail because `Javascript` is disabled by default in a webview [according to official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Enable Javascript and it will work, do this:

```
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I've tried this, including JavascriptInterface, it does not go the way I need. I will follow the guidance of Ankur and try via PWA.

Comment: But if you have a functional fact sample with JS, thank you!